# how to make 2 horizontal recycler views same width when they have different number of items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wanted to have 2 recyclerviews adding items in these on button click, to have same width at any time, so that I can scroll then together.

I know how to scroll them together, but for that they should have same width. I have tried by setting difference as margin of the last item, But the items that are out of screen will get recycled and not able to get their view.

Anyone have any idea for this?

Comment: Why do you want two recyclerview scroll at same time ?

Comment: Try setting layout params to the `View` in `onCreateViewHolder` like `view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`